# How would you abbreviate weekday schedules like "M-F" to less than 3 letters per day if the days contain Tuesday, Thursday, Saturday, and/or Sunday?

Tags: abbreviations, dashes, style-manuals

In some apps, there is a character limit, so instead of abbreviating something like "Tue-Thu" or "Sat-Sun", a few characters can matter, so I was wondering what the best way to abbreviate such days were.

"M-F" ("Mon-Fri") is no issue at all, but "T-T" and "S-S" runs into issues.

The following works well if everyone seems to understand the notation ([Dallas College usage](https://district.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/57/%7E/days-of-week-abbreviations#:%7E:text=The%20abbreviation%20for%20the%20days%20of%20the%20week%20are%3A&text=W%20%3D%20Wednesday,S%20%3D%20Saturday))

> T-R
>
> S-U

However, for everyday apps, that is unlikely the people would understand imo.

A mix of 1-letter and 2-letter abbreviations seems possible, but it might look inconsistent maybe.

> T-Th
>
> S-Su

2-letter abbreviations seem to be another option, though it could be redundant.

> Tu-Th
>
> Sa-Su

Another odd option I thought of is using 1 letter abbreviations without an en dash, and you assume that the reader assumes the order of the days start from Sunday to Saturday ([true in the United States and some others, but not other countries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Week#:%7E:text=While%2C%20for%20example%2C%20the%20United,first%20day%20of%20the%20week.))

> TWT
>
> SS

You could end up with something funny with the 1-letter combinations and an en dash if you do "Wed-Fri"

> WTF

...which is the abbreviation for an expression of surprise with a curse word.

Is there an established convention or a good recommendation for this?

Comment: Simple: Don't abbreviate it.

Comment: I used to use Θ for Thursday, in my private notes. I don't remember what I did about Saturday/Sunday: I suspect I used Σ for Sunday.

Comment: "Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa Su" would work. Although you definitely see "M Tu W Th F Sa Su" as well. I think in some countries they number the days of the week. This all seems a bit opinion-based, though.

Comment: @StuartF in some contexts days of the week are numbered in English, but does the week start on Sunday or Monday? 2-letter day abbreviations are at least established (though not as common as 3-letter) and compared to a mix of 1- and 2-letter codes have the benefits of consistent width and being individually unambiguous.

Comment: The UK bus industry used to have a standard format that supposedly never needed more than 5 characters to uniquely identify ***any*** combination of between 1 and 6 days of the week (if a service ran 7 days a week there was no need for a "DaysOfOperation" code string anyway). The actual days were represented by **M**onday **Tu**esday, **W**ednesday, **Th**ursday, **F**riday, **S**aturday, **Su**nday. A dash was used to mean all days within a range (**M-F** means "weekdays only"), and if any of those 1 or 2-character DayCodes came after **N** in the final string, those days were excluded.

Comment: **M-FNW** = Monday, Tuesday, Thursday, Friday (not Wednesday). Decades ago I had to write a subroutine to generate that DaysOfOperation string from a flag byte within which 7 of the 8 bits were used to indicate which days a bus service ran on. Nowadays we've got much better print formatting and display devices, so they usually use far more than 5 characters to make it really easy for the travelling public to read timetables without having to constantly refer to a list of abbreviations and formats used.